# Android. How to catch the moment when keyboard gets hidden?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I'm trying to catch the event of removing keyboard from the screen and i'm using the following code:

```
    searchTextField.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {

            System.out.println("ACTION ID " + actionId);

            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                System.out.println("ACTION DONE!!!!!!!!!!");
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

   searchTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
              if (hasFocus)
                  System.out.println("HAS FOCUS");
              else
                  System.out.println("FOCUS LOST");
        }
    });
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. `onEditorAction` just never called, no matter if i start editing or finish. Regarding `onFocusChange` method it's called just for the very first time when the keyboard goes up. When the keyboard goes down or when it goes up for the second time it's not called. Can anyone explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android. onEditorAction never called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202771/android-oneditoraction-never-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used GlobalLayoutListener on the activity rootView for checking that whether keyboard is hidden or visible:

It works as follows:

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
            if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                ... do something here
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: heh... thank you, buddy, but i just can't get how your answer relates to my question?

Comment: Using the code i have pasted yo get the event of keyboard is hidden or  keyboard is visible..

Comment: Using this you will receive an event if the user tries to hide the keyboard

Comment: put this in your activity's onCreate method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25531/discussion-between-karan-rana-and-andrey-chernukha)