# android edittext inputType:textpassword not working with intputType:actionDone on some devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype, imeoptions

I am not new to the use of `EditText`'s `inputType` but now I am having issue when setting `android:inputType="textPassword"` beside using `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Device used is: LG G4 Android v6.0

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                style="@style/TextInputLayoutLoginTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_padding_2"
                app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_password_visibility_18dp_selector"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white">

                <com.cashu.app.ui.widgets.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_activity_login_password"
                    style="@style/EditTextPasswordTheme"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="12"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/activity_consumer_login_password_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My code for this `EidtText`:

```
mEtPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) > 0 || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                login();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

mEtPassword.addTextChangedListener(new LoginTextWatcher(mEtPassword));
```

This is not working on my LG G4's device as well the `onEditorAction` method is not either called !

I tried so many searches and uses other people solutions but it seems a manufacturer issue !

Comment: No one answer this question yet? Guys, don't you have a solution?

Comment: Is your code working on any other device or simulator? If not, provide more code that could be related

Comment: @IulianPopescu, Yes, it works on other devices, but on some, its not :(

Comment: And the `onEditorAction` is never called, right? Or you wanted to say that the `login` method is not called?

Comment: @IulianPopescu, the `onEditorAction` method is never called

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202771/android-oneditoraction-never-called and change the `input type` to `text` for testing purposes. I would gladly do it, but I don't have the phone. Let me know what's happening when you change the input type.

Comment: what exactly you want to do with imeoptions  is only to detect enter key then I will give you another approch code

Comment: I think this related to password visibility toggle option. any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out.

I added this xml property to my `EditText`:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

I know its deprecated, but `android:maxLines="1"` not working although its the replacement for `singleLine`.

I also removed this:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Thank you guys for trying to help me.

Comment: If you removed actionDone then which event you are using to catch on editorqctionlistener

Comment: Please check my question. The default imeOption is none and its already handled in my code, but removing it and adding `singleLine` makes it to work

Answer (score 0):

try this to detect enter key

```
mEtPassword.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        // return false;
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                            //your necessary codes...

                        }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: I will try your answer tomorrow, thanks for answering me now

Answer (score -2):

Try using this method

```
edittext.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: not working, why using `setTransformationMethod` to `PasswordTransformationMethod` althought its using same xml attribute ?